# input() function handling data types differently across different Operating Systems?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am interested if anyone has seen this or if this is common knowledge.  Also, if this is the case for any other functions/methods?

If I have code that uses input(), the value input by the user *should* be a str data type.  In Windows, this seems to be very much the case.

If I run the same code in Mac/Linux, the OS seems to be "smart" enough to convert the data type to int.

Code example:

```
print("Enter multiple numbers, enter 0 to stop")
counter = 0
number_supplied = 1
sum = 0
while number_supplied !=0:
    number_supplied = input("")
    counter +=1
    sum = sum + number_supplied
print(sum/(counter-1))
```

If I run this code in Windows it (rightly) throws a TypeError.  If I run this in Mac or Linux, it does not.

Any thoughts, input (bad pun...sorry) would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: _"If I run the same code in Mac/Linux, the OS seems to be "smart" enough to convert the data type to int."_ That is... a little surprising tbh. It _shouldn't_ be doing this because according to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input), _"The function then reads a line from input, converts it to a string (stripping a trailing newline), and returns that."_ Are you _sure_ it converts to an int?

Comment: Are you sure there's no need for `int()` in mac/linux? Because I remember writing some codes a while back and they couldn't handle the numbers as strings

Comment: And besides AKX answer, it always raises an error in python3 no matter the platform.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're accidentally running the same code both on Python 2 (where `input()` parses values) and on Python 3 (where `input()` always returns strings).

Make sure you're running with `python3` on your Mac/Linux boxes, and remember you can verify the version of `python` with `python --version`.

Comment: That was it!!!!  Thanks.  I didn't even think to check the Python version.  Problem solved!